# Set maximum click rate jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a button which trigger an animation. My animation is actually a slide show, and the button is the forward button. But if I click this button (let's say...) 5 times in a second, the slide show will rotate, in my case, 5 containers, but each rotate animation is set to 400 miliseconds on each container. So that means that the total animation will take 2 seconds. What I say is that if I click continously the forward button for a second, the animation will takes 2 seconds to realise. So I want to set a maximum click rate. Let me be clear:

If I click the button right now, I want it to be inactive for 400 miliseconds (because as I said the animation is set to 400ms) so that the animation triggered with this button happen just once, even if I clicked that button (lets say...) 3 times in that interval. Afet 400 miliseconds it will be again ready to take another command.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

1. Start animation
2. Set button attribute disabled="disabled" so no one can trigger an animation
3. When animation finishes remove the attribute "disabled".

You can use "[animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations#Adding_the_animation_event_listeners)" event to watch the animation.

Answer (score 1):

you may use **[setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)** Method. The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.